# Distinct value in array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

Hello i have problem i have table

```
CREATE TABLE doctor(
idDoc SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
meds TEXT[]
);
```

I want to store only unique values if my user enter same meds inside

Table before user insert

| id | meds |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {Nalfon,Ocufen,Actron} |

After user insert (insert is Actron,Soma,Robaxin) i want update and have in table old values and new values ( **Actron** is same)
if I UPDATE table with new values I will get

```
UPDATE doctor SET meds='{Actron,Soma,Robaxin}') WHERE id=1;
```

| id | meds |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {Actron,Soma,Robaxin} |

But i want

| id | meds |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {Nalfon,Ocufen,Actron,Soma,Robaxin} |

I don't know how to check if new value is same like value in table and only insert/update table to have unique values.

Comment: That would be so easy with a properly normalized data model

Answer (score 1):

Given your data structure, you can unnest the existing meds, add in the new ones, and re-aggregate as a unique array:

```
UPDATE doctor d
    SET meds = (select array_agg(distinct med)
                from (select med
                      from unnest('{Actron,Soma,Robaxin}'::text[]) u(med)
                      union all
                      select med
                      from unnest(d.meds) u(med)
                     ) m
               )
    WHERE idDoc = 1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=43765b2abb603b7d5bd63d4dcfd9a975) is a db<>fiddle.

That said, you might consider a junction table with one row per doctor and medicine.  That is the more traditional SQL representation for a many-to-many relationship.